# spring batch oracle CLOB issue

Tags: spring-batch, apache-commons-dbcp

We are using spring batch which does insert some data as CLOB object in some of its table. We have oracle db and using apache commons dbcp connection pool. But when we run our job, it is throwing exception like below. What is the root cause of this issue? Is the issue in apache commons connection pool ?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
at oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(CLOB.java:979)
at oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(CLOB.java:939)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler$OracleLobCreator.prepareLob(OracleLobHandler.java:580)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler$OracleLobCreator.createLob(OracleLobHandler.java:527)
... 66 more
```

Comment: This article might help you https://community.oracle.com/thread/281238

Comment: I did check this article, but the problem is I dont want to chage spring batch framework lib which does use apache commons dbcp to insert data in spring batch tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar issue. Configuring an LOB handler fixed my issue. Please find the code below

```
<batch:job-repository data-source="dataSource" id="jobRepository"
    isolation-level-for-create="READ_COMMITTED" transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    table-prefix="${batch.table.prefix}" lob-handler="lobHandler" />

 <bean id="nativeJdbcExtractor" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.CommonsDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor"/>

     <bean id="lobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler">
        <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor" ref="nativeJdbcExtractor"/>
    </bean>
```